# Serializing Java objects into Oracle blob columns sometimes results in corrupted data

Tags: java, oracle, serialization, jms, blob

I use serialization to save some objects into Oracle Blob columns which I then extract and use in the same run or in other runs.

The serialization/deserialization looks like this:

```
public final class BytesTransformer {

static BytesTransformer btInstance = new BytesTransformer();
private ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
private ByteArrayInputStream bytesInputStream;
private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

public static BytesTransformer getInstance() {
    return btInstance;
}

private void initialiseInputStreams(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    bytesInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bytesInputStream);
}

private void initialiseInputStreams(InputStream bytes) throws IOException {
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bytes);
}

public byte[] getBytes(Serializable sObject) throws IOException {
    bytesOutputStream.reset();
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(sObject);
    objectOutputStream.close();

    return bytesOutputStream.toByteArray();
}

public Object fromBytes(byte[] dataBytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    initialiseInputStreams(dataBytes);
    Object sObject = objectInputStream.readObject();
    closeInputStreams();
    return sObject;
}

public Object fromBytes(InputStream dataBytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    initialiseInputStreams(dataBytes);
    Object sObject = objectInputStream.readObject();
    closeInputStreams();
    return sObject;
}

private void closeInputStreams() {
    try {
        if (objectInputStream != null) {
            objectInputStream.close();
        }
        if (bytesInputStream != null) {
            bytesInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

To write data to the blob column I use something like this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE CONFIGURATION_DEFINITION SET BYTES_DATA=? WHERE NAME=?", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
preparedStatement.setObject(1, BytesTransformer.getInstance().getBytes(cfgDef));
preparedStatement.setString(2, cfgDef.getName());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

To retrieve the data:

```
public ConfigurationDefinition getConfigurationDefinition(String configName) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    String sql = "SELECT BYTES_DATA FROM CONFIGURATION_DEFINITION WHERE NAME = '" + configName + "'";    
    ResultSet rs = getSQLConnector().executeQueryWithoutNoise(sql);
    try {
        if (rs == null || !rs.next()) {
            return null;
        }
        Blob blob = rs.getBlob(blobColumnName);
        bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        GatewayLogger.error("Unable to extract db records for configuration: " + configName, ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        getSQLConnector().closeResultSet(rs);
    }
    ConfigurationDefinition aDefinition = (ConfigurationDefinition) BytesTransformer.getInstance().fromBytes(buffer);        
    return aDefinition;
}
```

Most of the time there is no problem, but sometimes (quite rarely) and seemingly with no discernable pattern I get either:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: <first_byte>
```

or

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: <first_four_bytes>
```

When I get the second error I can usually find the correct header starting a few hundred bytes into the vector.

I should mention that the Oracle schema also holds some AQ JMS Queues which I use to send similarly serialized objects through and on a couple of occasions objects of those types were retrieved from the Oracle table even though there is no way that those two could get mixed up in the code.

I've looked around at discussions about those exceptions and nothing seems to apply to my case. Everything looks to be in order as far as I can tell and the exceptions only pop up very rarely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling these methods concurrently? Then synchronisation could be a case. Try making all methods "synchronized" or not depend on instance-variables.

Comment: Note that serialized objects should not really be used for long-term storage.

Comment: Ah, I see... You mean that while the output stream is writing for some thread, another one can hijack it can corrupt the message. That would make sense. I'll make the getBytes() and fromBytes() methods synchronized and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Or make judicious use of a couple of ThreadLocals. Will be better performing. Be sure to clean them up.